# parseInt, parseFloat, Number... i dont know

Tags: javascript

Hi Does someone know why this just wont work!! i have tried alsorts.

```
function loadJcrop(widthN, heightN){
    var run = true;
    if( run === true ) {
        alert(  parseInt(Number(widthN) / Number(heightN)) );
        jQuery(function(widthN, heightN) {
            jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                onChange: showCoords, onSelect: showCoords, aspectRatio: parseInt(Number(widthN) / Number(heightN))
              });       
        });
    }
}

jQuery(window).load(function() {
    loadJcrop(16, 1);
});
```

the alert returns 16 but nothing!!

and if i put

```
aspectRatio: 16
```

it works

any ideas??

Comment: Get rid of `jQuery(function(widthN, heightN) {` and the associated closing `});`

Comment: HAHAHAHHAHAHA good man!!

Answer (score 1):

First, I would make the calculations in one spot.  Second, I think you're better off Math.round.  Most importantly, however, you are using function parameters in your inner function, and I don't think you want to do that (it will unset the variables heightN and widthN).

I would re-write that function as:

```
function loadJcrop(widthN, heightN){
    // This is much clearer and easier to understand.
    var current = Math.round( Number(widthN) / Number(heightN) );
    var run = true;
    if( run ) { // if you have a variable which is a Boolean, 
                // you should not use '=='
        alert(  current );
        jQuery(function(/* Note the empty parameters */) {
                jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                        onChange: showCoords, onSelect: showCoords, aspectRatio: current)
              });       
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: works the same but i see where you are coming from... got a slight problem but i guess there is nothing i can do about that. Dont know if you have ever used jCrop but you can set an aspect ratio. using everything ive written the actual aspect is out slightly. But i think that may be due to the jCrop coding. Thanks.